# How to return a model still containing data from when view was rendered in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have been working with mvc for a little while now, but now im stuck with a problem that I didnt see come :)
The method in the controller returns a view with a model containing a Customer and Booking:

```
public class CustomerAndBooking
{
    public Customer customer { get; set; }
    public Booking booking { get; set; }
}
```

In my view i fill out the fields from the Booking. Very simple. The Customer is just being showed in the view and not modified. When I submit the view, the Booking in the model have all the data I choosed from the view, but the Customer is null?? I was hoping that the Customer would still be as it were when the controller first created the model.
How do I make it so my model is still intact when submitting the view??

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by add to view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.customer);
```

Comment: This is what I was about to post :o  To extend this a bit, you aren't getting the customer information on your post back because the MVC binding engine is only binding the data from html inputs on the form.  Since you didn't have any inputs for the customer data, it was never binding on the way back to the server.